# Part of HTML not visible for Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

**Set-up**

I'm using scrapy to scrape housing ads.

For each ad, I'm trying to obtain info on year of construction.

This info is stated in most ads.

---

**Problem**

I can see the year of construction and the other info around it in the about section when I check the ad in the browser and its HTML code in developer mode.

However, when I use Scrapy I get returned an empty list. I can scrape other parts of the ad page (price, rooms, etc.), but not the about section.

Check [this example ad](https://www.seloger.com/annonces/viagers/maison/fontainebleau-77/foret-de-fontainebleau/139747359.htm?abslc=new&enterprise=0&natures=1,2,4&places=%5B%7Bcp%3A77%7D%5D&projects=2,5&qsversion=1.0&types=1,2&bd=ListToDetail).

If I use `response.css('#caracteristique_bien').extract_first()`, I get,

```
<div id="caracteristique_bien"></div>
```

That's as far as I can go. Any deeper returns emptiness.

How can I obtain the year of construction?

Comment: Is it loaded dynamically in the browser and you maybe need Splash to render the page?

Comment: this is because of the site being rendered using javascript (most ads are). The solution to get this information is to use a browser emulator (like selenium) or to debug the requests done to the site and reverse-engineer it to understand how can that information be retrieved.

Comment: @alecxe: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm unfamiliar with Splash, so I can't say if you're right or wrong. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: @eLRuLL: ok. I need to scrape loads of ads, so Selenium is a no-go.

Comment: @alecxe would you mind sharing some links to check Splash?

Comment: @eLRuLL of course: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash. Now you learned something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, this is rendered using javascript, which means that some parts of the html will be loaded dynamically by the browser (`Scrapy`is not a browser).

The good thing for this case is that the javascript is inside the actual request, which means you can still parse the information that information, but differently.

for example to get the description, you can find it inside:

```
import re
import demjson

script_info = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Object.defineProperty")]/text()').extract_first() 

# getting description
description_json = re.search("descriptionBien', (\{.+?\});", script_info, re.DOTALL)
real_description = demjson.decode(description_json)['value']

# getting surface area
surface_json = re.search("surfaceT', (\{.+?\})\);", script_info, re.DOTALL).group(1)
real_surface = demjson.decode(surface_json)['value']

...
```

As you can see `script_info` contains all the information, you just need to come up with a way to parse that to get what you want

But there is some information that isn't inside the same response. To get it you need to do a GET request to:

```
https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=139747359
```

As you can see, it only requires the `idannonce`, which you can get from the previous response with:

```
demjson.decode(re.search("idAnnonce', (\{.+?\})\);", script_info, re.DOTALL).group(1))['value']
```

Later with the second request, you can get for example the "construction year" with:

```
import json

...

[y for y in [x for x in json.loads(response.body)['categories'] if x['name'] == 'Général'][0]['criteria'] if 'construction' in y['value']][0]['value']
```

Comment: Thanks, but impossible to find the construction year :-(

Comment: This is approach is totally new for me: I have no idea how it works. I'm getting a `NameError: name 'json' is not defined` when I run the last line to obtain the construction year. What should be placed in stead of the 'json'?

Comment: you need to import it: `import json`

Comment: Right... stupid. Ok, I did it but then I'm getting a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 337 column 1 (char 932)`.

Comment: check that the last code, should be applied against the response of `https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=139747359`, not the previous one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185260/discussion-between-elrull-and-lucspan).

Comment: @LucSpan I hope you were able to fix your problem.

Comment: I was. Thanks a lot for your explanation(s)! Seems you single-handedly upped my scraping skills to the next level ;-)

Comment: In the end I did `url = 'https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=139747359'` and `requests.get(url).json()` which gave a nice json.

Comment: Can I ask how you knew `https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=139747359` was needed?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, the add is loaded dynamically with javascript so you won't be able to get it via *scrapy*.

You can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for (massive) scraping (I did similar things on a famous french ads website)

Just use it headless with Chrome options and this will be fine :

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loaded the page, opened devtools of the browser, and did a `ctrl-F` with the css selector you used (`caracteristique_bien`), and found out this request: https://www.seloger.com/detail,json,caracteristique_bien.json?idannonce=139747359
where you can find what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. But I'm scraping a million ads. Your solution doesn't 'scale'

Comment: Then let me be more specific: use the url I provided as a template in your script spider. `idannonce` can be abstracted as a parameter whom value originates from where you get the URL you gave as example (here **139747359**).

Comment: Really @LucSpan ? 
Man, nothing is better than getting a JSON when trying to get internet data !! Scrapping is not reliable. JSON are !

Comment: The only issue is that you'll need cookies to get this :/

Comment: Everything related to cookies is handled by scrapy @LaSul. In the part of the spider that does the request, if you use for example [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to fetch the json, you can transfer the cookies from scrapy response to `requests`' request, so that not really a big issue

Comment: @LucSpan, based on your last comment on elRuLL answer, you should've listen to me right away :). Glad you solved your problem thanks to my indications